# JavaScript issue in Safari lower than 14

Tags: javascript, class, safari

I can't find reason why it's not working on safari lower then 14. After trying to fix it and looking in Google I give up.

It works everywhere except mine iPad 2, where is safari 13.3.1.
I checked more iOS devices with Safari under 14 and there was same issue.

It's working fine on version over 14.

Here is a cleaned up code

JavaScript

```
class Slider {

    constructor (src, options) {    
        Object.assign(this, options);
        this.quotes = document.querySelectorAll(src);
      }
    
    /* default options */
        slide = 0;       
        changeType = 'counter';       
        animation = 'from-left';
        duration = 1;
        amt = 'ease-in-out';

    /* set time interval for display slide */
    interval() {
        setInterval( () => {

            this.counter();
            this.show(this.slide);
            
        }, `${this.duration}000`)
    }
    
    /* 
    * 
    */
    randomSlide(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min+1) + min);
    }

    /* 
    * 
    */
    counter() {
        if (this.slide === this.quotes.length - 1)
            return this.slide = 0;
        else 
            return this.slide++;
        
    }

    /* 
    * show slide gived in parameter
    * @param nr
    */
    show(nr) {
            
            for (let i = 0; i <= this.quotes.length - 1; i++) {

                if (i === nr){
                    this.quotes[i].style.display = "inline-block";
                    this.quotes[i].style.setProperty("animation-duration", `${this.duration}s`);
                    this.quotes[i].style.setProperty("animation-timing-function", this.amt);
                    this.quotes[i].classList.add(this.animation);
                } else {
                    this.quotes[i].style.display = "none";
                }               
            }
              
    }
    /* 
    * initialize slideshow
    */
    init() {

        this.show(this.slide);
        this.interval();
       
    }    
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/qSlider.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id = "slider-top" class = "quotes-slider">
    <div class = "cite">      
      <q class = "dark">Veldig fornøyd. Anbefales!</q>        
      <p class = "ref-lg">Ola Nordmann - daglig leder</p>   
    </div>
    
    <div class = "cite">      
      <q class = "dark">Anbefales!</q>        
      <p class = "ref-lg">Ola Nordmann - daglig leder</p>   
    </div>

    <div class = "cite">      
      <q class = "dark">God srvise</q>        
      <p class = "ref-lg">Ola Nordmann - daglig leder</p>   
    </div>
  </div>
 
<script src = "js/qSlider.js"></script>
   <script>
        const sliderTop = new Slider("#slider-top .cite", {duration:4});
        sliderTop.init();
   </script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/* animations */ 
@keyframes fade-zoom-in {
    0% {opacity: 0} 
    50% {opacity: 1; transform: scale(1.1,1.1);}
    100% {opacity: 0}
}

:root{
    --duration: 0;
    --amt: 0;
}
/* quotes container */
.quotes-slider{
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.cite{
    display:none;  
}

/* animations classes */
.fade-zoom-in{
    animation-name: fade-zoom-in;
    animation-duration: var(--duration);
    animation-timing-function: var(--amt);
}
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Is there an error in the Web Developer console?

Comment: Nothing in Chrome, but i don't have tools to debug Safari

Comment: I think it should be obvious that I meant on the systems where it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default options public fields you have on your class did not have support in Safari until v14. You can define them in your constructor instead. [Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-14-release-notes#JavaScript)